# How to find all the file names in a specific directory without using "dirent.h" (visual studio 2017 windows) in C

Tags: c, file

I have a mid-semester project, to make an anti-virus, that get as main arguments a directory and a path:
The path is to a file that contains a virus signature. The anti-virus's goal is to scan all the files in the given directory for the virus signature.
I've finished the whole project, except the part that finds all the files in a specific given directory. Since this project is checked by an auto-feedback system that doesn't have any external libraries and operates on an **unknown operating system** (even my instructor don't know, it's the course's system), it has to be a cross-platform solution that doesn't rely on any libraries but stdio.h, stdlib.h, string.h and windows.h

Almost every tutorial and example of doing this is with HANDLE (which we haven't learned yet, and not supposed to use) or with .
The problem is to find a way of doing it without dirent library.

I need some function that gets all the files in a directory

Something like this:

```c
char** fileNames = somefunc(char* dir)
```

Comment: That *can't* be done without some sort of library. File traversal is not standard C. You need to make calls to the OS.

Comment: This might be a better question for your instructor: the one who placed these (supposed) limitations on you.

Comment: I can use windows.h though...

Comment: Sorry if my question is not sorted or something I've just registered to Stack Overflow.

Comment: There's no "cross-platform solution" to do this. You need to use operating system native functionality for this. Perhaps it's time for you to ask your teacher for clarifications?

Comment: *we haven't learned yet, and not supposed to use* If your instructor discourages learning on your own and using what you have learned, consider finding a different instructor.

Comment: As for Windows, the native solution is to use [`FindFirstFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) and [`FindNextFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilea) (which will be declared if you include `<windows.h>`).

Comment: @n.m. He doesn't discourages us to not learn by ourselves new things, but the course's plan is for us to "break our heads" trying to figure this problem out, without using HANDLE, and in the next lesson, after this project, we learn how to use them.

Comment: @LiorLevin If the goal is for you to "break your heads", tell him that you already did and you know there is no answer. It's like asking someone to add 28 + 17 without teaching them carries — the solution is "you can't"; you have to learn carries. (Also, your instructor is lying to you. If you can use `<windows.h>`, he _knows_ the OS is Windows.)

Comment: Ok thanks for helping, it might even just be a trick question. I'll try to use HANDLE for it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this with the standard library alone; standard C has no knowledge of directories. Every OS has a way of doing this, though, so you'll want to find the OS family for your checker (Windows, Linux, etc.) and look up how to do it for that OS.

Libraries built into the OS must be available, since they come with the system. You cannot run *any program at all* without them. (This is technically not true, but it's accurate enough to cover all interesting cases.)

EDIT: if your checker runs under Windows (judging from your comments), you'll want to use `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`. They do rely on handles, though (like virtually all of the Windows API), so you'll have to look into that. (A handle is just an opaque pointer with special meaning to the Windows kernel. You can treat it pretty much like a `void *`. Don't get too fixated on the data type.)

EDIT 2: if you're looking for something to get you started:

```
char ** list_directory (const char * directory) {
  char * search_path = malloc(strlen(directory) + 3);
  strcpy(search_path, directory);
  strcat(search_path, "\\*");
  WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
  SetLastError(0);
  HANDLE hsrch = FindFirstFile(search_path, &fd);
  free(search_path);
  if (hsrch == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) return NULL;
    SetLastError(0);
    return calloc(1, sizeof(char *)); // no files
  }
  char ** result = malloc(sizeof(char *));
  unsigned count = 0;
  while (!GetLastError()) {
    result[count] = malloc(strlen(fd.cFileName) + 1);
    strcpy(result[count ++], fd.cFileName);
    FindNextFile(hsrch, &fd);
    result = realloc(result, (count + 1) * sizeof(char *));
  }
  if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    SetLastError(0);
  FindClose(hsrch);
  result[count] = NULL;
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dirent.h` header is a POSIX implementation of traversing directories, meaning it runs only on UNIX-like systems.  For Windows you should use the `_findfirst` and `_findnext` functions as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/findfirst-functions?view=vs-2017).  Unlike `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` these do not use a `HANDLE`.

For example:

```
intptr_t ffhandle;
struct _finddata_t ffinfo;

if ((ffhandle = _findfirst("c:\\path\\to\\dir\\*.*", &ffinfo)) == -1) {
    perror("findfirst failed");
    exit(1);
}
do {
    printf("found file %s\n", ffinfo.name);
} while (_findnext(ffhandle, &ffinfo) == 0);
_findclose(ffhandle);
```

Comment: That's just a handle cast to `intptr_t`, though.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 There's no cast.  The functions are declared to return `intptr_t`.

Comment: The cast is in the implementation of the functions. `HANDLE` is an opaque pointer type.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789, the relationship of the number returned by `_findfirst` to a `HANDLE` is both unspecified and irrelevant.  If the OP is forbidden from relying on the `HANDLE` type then this approach achieves that.